# Returning a variable outside closure

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to check the number of posts in my database and return it as the numberOfRows in my tableView. However, the below code does not work. It returns 1 everytime. I know it's because I'm setting the var requestPostCount inside a closure, but I'm not sure on how to fix it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            var requestPostcount: Int = 1

            if segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

                // This is temporary
                return 1
            }

            else {
                // Query the database to check how many posts are there
                ref.child("Request Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    var requestPostCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

                    // If database is empty, only 1 row is needed to display error message
                    if requestPostCount == 0 {
                        requestPostCount = 1
                    }
                })
            }

            return requestPostcount
        }
```

Comment: Your need to load the data before loading the table view.

Answer (score 0):

numberOfRowsInSection is the wrong place to be querying your database.

At any rate, the method will return requestPostcount with your default value before the closure finishes executing.

You need to find a better place to query your database so that when numberOfSections is called, the data is already available.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how async methods work. You can't do an async query of a remote database in your numberOfRows method and return a value.

It's not possible to have a function that calls an async method return the results of the async method as a function result.

You need to set up your model to have no data in it, send the database query, parse the results, and then, in the completion closure, update your model and then, on the main thread, tell the table view to update.

Comment: It's not possible to have a function that calls an async method return the results of the async method as a function result. -> Sure you can, if you wait on the result. Definitely not desirable in a `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection:)` method call, though

Comment: @Alexander: Well, No. That turns the async function into a synchronous function. Thus my statement stands.

Comment: Perhaps a matter of terminology, but the async function is still async. The async function call is performed, and execution continues on to the next instructions. It just so happens that one of those following instructions is a blocking wait

Answer (score 0):

You need to load data in ViewDidLoad . after getting data then reload tableview,

var requestPostcount: Int = 1 // declared variable

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.child("Request Posts").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var requestPostCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

        // If database is empty, only 1 row is needed to display error message
        if requestPostCount == 0 {
            requestPostCount = 1
        }
        tblView.reloadData()
    })
  }
```

Now **numberOfRowsInSection** as below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         if segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                return 1
            }
         else {
            return requestPostcount
        }
```